# Compilation program with libftd2xx library on ARM platform

Tags: compilation, arm, dynamic-linking, ftdi

I try to compile program in C, dedicated for FTDI chip. My enviroment is Advanced Tomato based Asus router + 16GB USB mem stick, mounted as /opt. Additionaly I have compiler + dependences + the newest FTDI library for ARMv7 from FTDI web site.

My compilation command is:

```
gcc -v -Wl,-rpath=/opt/usr/local/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -L/opt/usr/local/lib -O2 -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -fno-caller-saves -mfloat-abi=soft -l ftd2xx arco.c -o arco
```

Library patch is:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/usr/lib:/opt/include:/opt/usr/local/lib:/opt/usr/include
```

Below verbose output from compilation process. Strange think is that in the first part of compilation, location od dynamic linker is correct, that is:

```
/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

But in the second part is wrong, that is:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

It is not possible to copy/link ld-linux.so.3 to /lib because it is read only filesystem.

All this cause that when I run program, an library error occurs:

```
./arco: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so: internal error
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Compilation output:

```
   Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /media/ware3/Entware-ng.2016.08/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9_glibc-2.23_eabi/gcc-5.4.0/configure --target=arm-openwrt-linux --host=arm-openwrt-linux --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --program-suffix= --prefix=/opt --exec-prefix=/opt --bindir=/opt/bin --sbindir=/opt/sbin --libexecdir=/opt/lib --sysconfdir=/opt/etc --datadir=/opt/share --localstatedir=/opt/var --mandir=/opt/man --infodir=/opt/info --disable-nls --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-bugurl=https://dev.openwrt.org/ --with-pkgversion='OpenWrt GCC 5.4.0' --enable-shared --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-target-optspace --with-gnu-ld --with-stage1-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath=/opt/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3' --with-boot-ldflags='static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-rpath=/opt/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3' --disable-nls --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libvtv --disable-libcilkrts --disable-libmudflap --disable-multilib --disable-libgomp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-decimal-float --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-host-libstdcxx=-lstdc++ --prefix=/opt --libexecdir=/opt/lib --with-local-prefix=/opt --with-float=soft --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (OpenWrt GCC 5.4.0) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/opt/usr/local/lib' '-O2' '-pipe' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtune=cortex-a9' '-fno-caller-saves' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-o' 'arco' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabi arco.c -quiet -dumpbase arco.c -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=soft -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase arco -O2 -version -fno-caller-saves -o - |
 as -v -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -o /opt/tmp/ccMeNAyM.o
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.26.1
GNU C11 (OpenWrt GCC 5.4.0) version 5.4.0 (arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=47 --param ggc-min-heapsize=31954
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/../../../../arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/include
 /opt/include
 /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C11 (OpenWrt GCC 5.4.0) version 5.4.0 (arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=47 --param ggc-min-heapsize=31954
Compiler executable checksum: a589712d81e28a1300ccb0e03d994135
COMPILER_PATH=/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/:/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/:/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/:/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/:/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/:/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/opt/usr/local/lib' '-O2' '-pipe' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtune=cortex-a9' '-fno-caller-saves' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-o' 'arco' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/collect2 -plugin /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/opt/tmp/ccOsGCvJ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.3 -X -m armelf_linux_eabi -o arco /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/crt1.o /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/crti.o /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/opt/usr/local/lib -L/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0 -L/opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/../../.. -rpath=/opt/usr/local/lib --dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -lftd2xx /opt/tmp/ccMeNAyM.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/crtend.o /opt/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/crtn.o
```

Comment: You can over-mount `/lib` with a ram filesystem and create the link, if the current contents of `/lib` are small.  Alternatively when you build you need to have the ld-linux.so.3 in the proper location as it will be on the target.  Typically you have a shadow filesystem on the build machine that will match the target exactly.  Otherwise, you have issues like you do.  Instead of *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* you pass a `--prefix` option to configure, but it depends on the tools your build uses.

Comment: I dont know how to cross-mount /lib and I have enough room to copy  ld-linux.so.3 to /lib. But it is read only filesys. Next, I develop my build directly on target unit that I want to use in future. Moreover i dont know how to use --prefix option. Sorry for my ignorance but I am new in ARM world.